# Problem with SQL FULL OUTER JOIN with WHERE date

Tags: sql

this query return result of all row with P500 & S500, except that the prj_end_dt won't work at all it simply ignore it is there a way to make it work?

thank you,

```
SELECT project_labour.cod_no,project.prj_no,project.prj_end_dt,project_labour.pla_hrs_budg 
FROM project_labour 
FULL OUTER JOIN project ON project_labour.prj_no=project.prj_no 
WHERE project_labour.cod_no='S500' OR project_labour.cod_no='P500' AND prj_end_dt<'2019-01-01'
```

Comment: Your title says "inner join".  Your code says "full join".  Which is it?

Comment: use bracket for your OR condition ( OR ) AND prj_end_dt<'2019-01-01'

Comment: my bad I was trying out full outer join but at first it was INNER JOIN

Comment: thank you bracket was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FULL JOIN` is almost never necessary.  I rarely use it, and I write *lots* of queries.  Filtering is even more troublesome.  I am guessing that you really want:

```
SELECT pl.cod_no, p.prj_no, p.prj_end_dt, pl.pla_hrs_budg
FROM project p LEFT JOIN
     project_labour pl
     ON pl.prj_no = p.prj_no AND pl.cod_no IN ('S500', 'P500')
WHERE p.prj_end_dt < '2019-01-01';
```

This will return all projects from prior to 2019.  Any matching `project_labour` rows will be returned.  If there are none, then those columns will be `NULL`.  It is quite possible that an `INNER JOIN` is sufficient for the query; the `IN` condition fixes the problem with your logic.